# End of method reached but compiler jumps back in

Tags: c#

just for fun I am trying to do the change making problem - more or less. My problem is that I get doubled results and through using the debugger I found out that the compiler jumps back into the method again even when it should finish.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
string temp = Console.ReadLine();
int input;

if (int.TryParse(temp, out input))
{
    if(input == 0)
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);
    }
    else
    {
        ChangeMaking(input);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a number.");
}
}

private static int ChangeMakingHelper(int input, int euro)
{
    return input / euro;
}

static int[] euro = { 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500 };
static int counter = 0;
static List<int[]> result = new List<int[]>();
static int[] tempResult = new int[euro.Length];

private static void ChangeMaking(int input)
{
    for (int i = euro.Length -1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(euro[i] <= input)
        {
            tempResult[i] = ChangeMakingHelper(input, euro[i]);
            input = input - euro[i];
            if((input % euro[i] != 0))
            {
                ChangeMaking(input % euro[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    result.Add(tempResult);
}
```

For example if the input is 11 then after the for-loop completes and adding `tempResult` to `result` the compiler jumps back into this part:

```
            if((input % euro[i] != 0))
            {
                ChangeMaking(input % euro[i]);
            }
```

My expected behavior for input 11 would be one array with this values `{1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` which I get but doubled.

Comment: If input is 11, then `ChangeMaking` called twice with 11 and with 1 as argument.

Comment: It works fine when I run it on .Net fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/d0LfSu. How are you calling `ChangeMaking`?

Comment: Oh I think I get it... your problem is that `result` has 2 arrays in it?

Comment: I added my main method which contains the way how I call ChangeMaking. Yes result has 2 arrays in the end

Comment: You are using recursion, so what you are seeing is the stack unwinding.

Comment: Basically what is going on is that you are recursing into `ChangeMaking`, since that method adds a static array to a list at the end, each time you recurse you add a whole new copy to the list. In the the case of 11 as an input, you recurse once, calling `ChangeMaking` twice, and appending the array twice. Its the same twice because arrays are reference types even though the values are value types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using static variables to pass data between function calls. Don't do that. Use return values instead.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var result = ChangeMaking(11);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
}

private static int ChangeMakingHelper(int input, int euro)
{
    return input / euro;
}

static readonly int[] euro = { 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500 };

private static int[] ChangeMaking(int input)
{
    var result = new int[euro.Length];
    for (int i = euro.Length -1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (euro[i] <= input)
        {
            result[i] += ChangeMakingHelper(input, euro[i]);
            input = input - euro[i];
            if (input % euro[i] != 0)
            {
                var tempResult = ChangeMaking(input % euro[i]);
                // Transfer the results to the local result array
                for(int j = 0; j < result.Length; j++)
                    result[j] += tempResult[j];
            }
            // Also add a break statement here so you don't add the lower values twice!
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7WnLWN

By the way, the reason you ended up with 2 arrays in your output is because you called `ChangeMaking` recursively, so it got called twice, so it called `result.Add(tempResult)` twice. Getting rid of the static variables as I have shown above fixes that.

Also, there's probably a more efficient way to do this without recursion, but that would require restructuring your algorithm a bit, so I'll leave that to you to figure out :)

Comment: Efficient as in? Faster? Memory? I can only think about doing a iterative approach but this was the first time where I naturally thought a recursive approach was the right thing to do. If I am not wrong recursion uses more memory than an iterative approach..

Comment: Both (faster and less memory). Also, if your input is extremely large, and you use a recursive approach, you may run into stack overflow issues.

Comment: I wouldn't say either approach is right or wrong. If performance is critical, I would go with an iterative approach. If you are not planning on running this function thousands of times per second, and a recursive approach makes more sense to you, then the recursive approach is fine.